# Copy multiple tabs into a new workbook, paste as values

Tags: excel, vba

I have code to paste several tabs in. However, I'm not sure how to paste them as values without altering the source code as little as possible.

I think it's currently using the default of `.Copy` copying into a new workbook, so I think I may have to declare the new workbook explicitly, but not sure.

```vb
Sub ExportTabs(Boro As String)
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'ExportTabs
'This subroutine exports separate tabs into new workbooks. It will take in a borough and export it into a workbook,
'saved in the same directory as the master workbook. The export will be a copy paste
'of values and formatting.
'
'Parameters: Boro (String)
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

'Step 1:    Declare your variables
    Dim MasterFile As Workbook
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim LeadingText As String
    Dim DateT As String


'Step 2:    Set file name strings, including hard-coding the header text
    LeadingText = "Completion Report - "
    DateT = Format(DateTime.Date, "MM-dd-yy")


'Step 3:    Find active workbook and relevant sheet, and copy and save with new file name
    Set MasterFile = ActiveWorkbook
    FileName = MasterFile.Path & "\" & LeadingText & DateT & " " & Boro & ".xlsx"
    MasterFile.Sheets(Array(Boro & " Completion Report", Boro & " Summary", "About")).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName, FileFormat:=51

'Step 4:    Close new workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: So you want to move the sheets over and break the link? I have a code written for this already we can change as needed. Is it more important that the values are values or that it isn't referencing the old file? (The difference being any formulas referencing them would be stored a values, but anything self-sustaining in the tab would be untouched)

Comment: The links are currently referencing a tab called 'Completion Report' in the master file. For links to work, they would need to break that link, and then reference a tab called `Boro & " Completion Report` in the current file.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question and that is different from what you described in your question. Are you trying to paste everything as values, only breaking links (pastes only references as value), or are you trying to change the reference completely to another sheet on the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up altering the code under `Step 3` to this:

```
    Set MasterFile = ActiveWorkbook
    FileName = MasterFile.Path & "\" & LeadingText & DateT & " " & Boro & ".xlsx"
    MasterFile.Sheets(Array(Boro & " Completion Report", Boro & " Summary", "About")).Copy
    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        'Only copy and paste as values in Summary tab
        If sht.Name = Boro & " Summary" Then
            sht.UsedRange.Copy
            sht.UsedRange.PasteSpecial xlValues
            sht.UsedRange.PasteSpecial xlFormats
        End If
    Next sht
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName, FileFormat:=51
```

I found out that `.Copy` copies to a new workbook Excel recognizes as `ActiveWorkbook`, so you can change the workbook from there. The only way to paste as values seems to be the `.PasteSpecial xlValues` method.